# How to use @Before advice with multiple pointcuts?

Tags: rest, spring-mvc, annotations, aspectj, spring-aop

I have written a  @Before advice to be invoked for the following methods which belong to same class named as MPIController.

```
TransactionType
```

is my custom annotation interface.

And the methods are:

```
1.
@RequestMapping(value = "/getPatient", method = { RequestMethod.POST,RequestMethod.PUT }, consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
@TransactionType(value = "FETCH_PATIENT")
public @ResponseBody
FetchPatientResponse fetchPatientDemographics(
        @RequestBody String jsonObject, HttpServletResponse response,
        HttpServletRequest request, BindingResult error) {
       ...
       }
```

..

```
2.
@TransactionType(value = "UPDATE_PATIENT")
private PersistResponse updatePatient(String jsonObject,String patientDemo,
        String fromCode) {..}
```

..

```
3. 
@TransactionType(value = "REGISTER_PATIENT")
private PersistResponse RegisterPatient(String jsonObject,String patientDemo,
        String fromCode) {..}
```

My advice looks like this.

```
@Before("execution(* com.rest.controller.MPIController.*(..)) &&args(jsonObject,..) && @annotation(transactionType) ")
public void log(String jsonObject,TransactionType transactionType){..}
```

The @Before advice is invoked properly for "fetchPatientDemographics() method,however it does not work for the rest two methods.

Can you tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Method 2 and 3 are being called from some other method in the same class.They are not directly invoked.Can that be an issue?

Comment: Spring AOP can only advice public methods. If you want to advice private methods as well, you will have to use a different AOP implementation, like plain AspectJ.

Comment: Hi @sheltem ,aspectj is what i am using but the problem still persists.

Comment: And even if I make both those methods public,it still does not work!

Comment: This sounds as if you *think* you are using AspectJ, but in reality you are still using Spring AOP (which has nothing in common with AspectJ except for the syntax). Maybe you want to double-check and/or post a full Spring sample including config file.